# Uncaught error Fullcalendar is not a function

Tags: custom-list, error, sharepoint-calendar

I am using FullCalendar v3.10.2 and trying to run a script to prevent multiple day selection. I searched and found that the full calendar function is not recognized.

I am not sure what to do. My script is as follows (I have mentioned the HTML tags first which is being used in a separate file):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/PreventMultiSelect.js"></script>

$(function(){

var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();


$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

       selectable: true,
      selectHelper: true,
      editable: true,
      defaultView: 'agendaMonth',
  
      select: function (start, end) {
          var mEnd = $.fullCalendar.moment(end);
          var mStart = $.fullCalendar.moment(start);
  
          if (mEnd.isAfter(mStart, 'day')) {
              $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
          } else {
              $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                  start: mStart,
                  end: mEnd,
                  allDay: false
              },
              true // stick the event
              );
              $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
          }
      }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is full calendar library file is not loading properly on page. Check if file is loaded or not using browser's developer tools. Also, make sure file is loaded before calling `.fullCalendar()` function.

OR

First try using CDN path for full calendar and check if it works, like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.2/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            editable: true,
            defaultView: 'agendaMonth',
            select: function (start, end) {
                var mEnd = $.fullCalendar.moment(end);
                var mStart = $.fullCalendar.moment(start);

                if (mEnd.isAfter(mStart, 'day')) {
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
                } else {
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                        start: mStart,
                        end: mEnd,
                        allDay: false
                    },
                        true // stick the event
                    );
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

If this works as expected then download the library file, upload in SharePoint library, use correct path in script tag and then verify that the file is loaded on page using browser's developer tool.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ganesh Sanap! I ll just try and tell you the results.

Comment: Sure, let me know if it works or you come across any issue using this approach.

Comment: Hello Ganesh...I tried using the source you told, but still its not working. While debuggin and executing the breakpoint at the fullcalendar function definition statement, the control goes to the end of the function. So, I am not sure it is executing.I even tried using selectConstraint and EventConstraint, but the flow goes to the end of the function.

Comment: Update: As it was not working, I put a validation on the Add button with condition of start date and end dates being equal in order to allow the user to make an entry, otherwise an alert should appear.